# Some Firebase Functionality Asks me to Create a Billing Account Before I complete my app?

Tags: flutter, dart

for example, I have two Actors in my flutter applications, owner and Customer, if The Customer Posts into Firestore, The User Should be Notified Based on his Location and His app Engagement,

I am trying to achieve this by using Firebase Cloud Function but Google asks me to open a billing account, I Can't do that because there is no Payment method in my country, please Recommend me if There is a way to achieve that.

What I want is to Notify the User. Based on his Locations and his app Engagement, if there are any means to achieve these please Recommend me? if not what shall I do??

Answer (score 0):

You have different payment methods, depending on the country, I recommend that you verify if some of all these payment methods (attached photo) are available in your country.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2380700

If you still can't, ask someone to make a service account so you can use the API.
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts
[image]
[image]

Comment: I live In Ethiopia( East Africa) i can't open the account and also i have no friend to open a service account, I Develop an app that  is a new idea and if I completed Successfully I think that I hope to make millions of dollar, but I stop now from doing because the app is Really Depends on Notifications that uses Cloud-function, Please brother can you help me to open the account if you can, I will give you my detail information, i want to Start Friendship with you. +251945178528, my Telegram number, please inbox me

Comment: I want to ask you one Questions, my APP Is Really Depends on Notifications, for examples is the app has two actors, owner and user, if the owner posts something, the user must be notified, based on their locations, which means the System first searches the nearest user and notify him, Notification is performed based on the location of the user, the user who is found in the nearest location is notified first, so What I want to ask you is it possible to achieve this without using firebase Cloud functions,